# Passing database class object from main activity to another activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to implement simple database CRUD operations, in case of UPDATE operation user moves to another screen where he inputs the new and old values for the column he wants to update, So while moving to next activity I want to pass the object of database class created in MainActivity to UpdateActivity, I tried it by implementing the Database class Serializbale but it crashes.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object
```

Here is the code i tried

MainActivity

```
MyDbHandler dbObj = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

public void updateBtnClicked(View view)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityUpdate.class);
    intent.putExtra("Object", dbObj);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

ActivityUpdate

```
intent = getIntent();

dbObj2 = (MyDBHandler) intent.getSerializableExtra("Object");

public void doneButtonClicked(View view)
{

    String str1 = newValue.getText().toString();
    String str2 = oldValue.getText().toString();

    dbObj2.updateProduct(str1, str2);

    finish();

}
```

So how could the database class object be passed from one to another activity? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how could the database class object be passed from one to another activity

You don't serialize Database objects. You request them again.

```
MyDbHandler dbHandler = new MyDbHandler(MainActivity.this);  // pass your Activity here 
dbHandler.update(new Foo(42));
```

Where `MyDbHandler` is some extension of `SQLiteOpenHelper` written like so

```
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Info
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DatabaseName";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            // TODO
        }

    /**
     * Update method defined here
    **/
    public void update(Foo bar) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        // TODO: Write to & close the database
    }
}
```

Comment: This means that in each Activity we want to perform some DB operation we have create a new object of DB class and passing the current Activity as context? e.g in my case what you suggested that creating the object of DB class in MainActivity that is what I am already doing but the update task I want to perform from another activity ActivityUpdate and same line of code as you mentioned in the first line but ActivityUpdate would be there in place of MainActivity ?

Comment: Correct, I just have an example. You simply need a Context

Answer (score 1):

MyDbHandler must extend Serializable to be correctly serialized.

Comment: cricket_007 is correct that serialization is not necessary for database handler instantiation. Follow his advice in this case.

Comment: if you feel you are incorrect, you may delete the answer. That's up to you, though

Comment: I feel that this advice is worth preserving, as the original error shehzy posted was a serialization error.  It's worth mentioning for future reference, regardless of whether fixing the serialization is necessary in this case.